# How to get the object which bool value is YES from nested sets of objects with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have three models below:

Show.h

```
@class Season;

@interface Show : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *seasons;

@end
```

Season.h

```
@class Episode, Show;

@interface Season : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * season;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *episodes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Show *Show;

@end
```

Episode.h

```
@class Season;

@interface Episode : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * watched;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Season *season;

@end
```

The relationships are: Show has many seasons and Season has many episodes, and Episode has a watched bool value. Right now I want to get the next Episode which it's watched value is NO from it's Show. How to write this predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your episodes are unordered, add `number` property to `Episode` entity.

Updated the answer. Basically you add sort descriptors so that the values are returned by season's `season` property, which I assume to be its number and by a new `Eposode`'s property called `number`

```
- (Episode *)nextUnwatchedEpisodeForShow:(Show *)show
{
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Episode class])];
  fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"season.Show == %@ && watched == %@", show, @NO];
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"season.season" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES]];
  return [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] firstObject]; // first object should be the first unwatched episode, if it's nil then all the episodes were watched
}
```

Comment: But I want to get one particular show's episode? If doing like yours, I am searching through all of shows' episodes.

Comment: You are getting one specific episode with this approach. Search descriptors are set to return unwatched episodes with the lowest `number` first. Basically you're getting the first unwatched episode for the season as was specified in your question.

Comment: The show may has many seasons. I need get first unwatched episode for a show. It's going through the first season, and then the second and so on to find the first unwatched episode.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. The predicate format logic really hard to get.